# Multiprocessing Pool return results as available

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing, pool

I'm trying to implement multiprocessing and struggling to get where I need to get.

So some background I have previously done multiprocessing with Celery, so I am used to being able to send jobs to a worker and poll when its done, and get the results of the job even if other jobs are going.  I'm trying to relate this to multiprocessing.  Here is what I have so far, dug up from various sites I have found...

```
import urllib2
import time
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
import random

def openurl(url):
    time.sleep(random.randrange(1,10))
    print url
    return urllib2.urlopen(url)


urls = [
  'http://www.python.org',
  'http://www.python.org/about/',
  'http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/python/2003/04/17/metaclasses.html',
  'http://www.python.org/doc/',
  'http://www.python.org/download/',
  'http://www.python.org/getit/',
  'http://www.python.org/community/',
  'https://wiki.python.org/moin/',
  'http://planet.python.org/',
  'https://wiki.python.org/moin/LocalUserGroups',
  'http://www.python.org/psf/',
  'http://docs.python.org/devguide/',
  'http://www.python.org/community/awards/'
  # etc..
  ]

pool = ThreadPool(20)

results = pool.map(openurl, urls)

pool.close()
pool.join()
print 'now what'
```

So I am kicking off the openurl function on my urls, but if I break at "print 'now what'", it does not break there until all my jobs are complete.

How can I 'poll' my threads and return the results as they come in?

Thanks!

Comment: Not at all clear about what you actually mean here. What results are you talking about? More detail please.

Answer (score 2):

`pool.map` distributes the iterable elements over a Pool of Workers and aggregates the results when they are all ready.

Moreover, `pool.close` and `pool.join` instruct the Pool to wait until all the tasks are done.

If you want to handle the results as they come, you have to use `pool.apply_async` and use a callback. Or you can collect the [AsyncResult](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult) objects returned by `pool.apply_async` and iterate over them to see when each of those is ready but the whole logic would be quite cumbersome.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

pool = ThreadPool(20)
tasks = []

def callback(result):
    # handle the result of your function here
    print result

for url in urls:
    pool.apply_async(openurl, args=[url], callback=callback)

pool.close()
pool.join()
```